# Infinite recursion in JavaScript quicksort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Here is the [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) code I wrote. The function doesn't work because it can't reach the base case. If I log the pivot, `r` and `l` to the console, they remain the same no matter how many times the sort function is called. So I wonder if the argument `l`, `r` are not really passed into the function as data. Why did it happen?

```
function sort(data){
    if(data.length < 2){
        return data;
    }
    else{
        var l = [];
        var r = [];
        var pivot = parseInt(data.length/2);
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] > data[pivot]){
                r.push(data[i]);
            }
            else{
                l.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        return sort(l).concat(sort(r));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting l and r each recursive call.  You should init them outside of your sort function.

Comment: @marteljn Yes. But if i put console.log(l) before the return, it prints the same arrays.So I am confused

Comment: I have to ask: What's wrong with just calling `originalArray.sort()`?

Comment: @marteljn- Are you sure about that?  Won't each call get its own stack frame and its own local copy of `l` and `r`?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

I think that the issue here is that your partitioning step does not necessarily shrink the input array.  For example, let's trace what happens if you try sorting [1, 2].  In this case, your pivot element will be the element 2.  Since 1 > 2 is false, 1 is added to the list `l`.  Since 2 > 2 is false, 2 is added to the list `l`.  As a result, your recursive call on the list `l` will have exactly the same arguments as your original call, causing infinite recursion.

To fix this, try splitting the input into three lists - one of smaller values, one of equal values, and one of greater values.  This code is shown here:

```
function sort(data){
  if (data.length < 2){
    return data;
  } else {
    var l = [];
    var r = [];
    var e = [];
    var i = 0;
    var pivot = (data.length / 2) | 0;

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i] > data[pivot]) {
        r.push(data[i]);
      } else if (data[i] < data[pivot]) {
        l.push(data[i]);
      } else {
        e.push(data[i]);
      }
    }  
    return sort(l).concat(e, sort(r)); 
  }
}
```

This new version explicitly groups the equal elements into their own list, so they aren't recursively sorted by either of the recursive calls.  It also gracefully handles duplicate elements.

Comment: @Bergi- Thanks!  I'm by no means a JS programmer, and I didn't know that you could do that.

Comment: gg Randall.  Let's get some stats on API access calls against the `sort` tag? :)

Comment: I bet @templatetypedef gained a lot of reputation today because of that stacksort implementation :)

Comment: Up voted solely because this worked in the hilarious stacksort project (http://gkoberger.github.com/stacksort/)

Comment: And @templatetypedef is wondering why is answer is having so much popularity now ... thanks to stacksort ;)

Comment: @glebm If I'm not mistaken, the memory usage here is proportional to the runtime, so this only uses O(n^2) memory in degenerate cases.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, O(n log n) on average, O(n^2) when every pivot ends up to the left every time

Comment: First stacksort result that doesn't use `Array.prototype.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

If you pick the largest value of the array as the pivot element, then all values of `data` will end up in the array `l` and none in `r`. Thus will make the recursion never stop (and keep `l`, `r` and `pivot` at the same values).
Unless this is a brain excercise, using `data.sort()` should do a better job. ;)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript passes objects by reference (arrays are objects too). If you want to pass them by value, you need to use the splice function as explained [here](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/).

Note that this will create a lot of copies of your data. You probably want to use the native sort() function.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here.  The infinite recursion is not because of pass-by-reference, but due to the fact that the original code does not correctly handle one of the cases it needs to handle.

Comment: your question doesn't mention anything about infinite recursion, rather about the variables not changing...